# Is my database good for hierarchical data? I want to write a SQL query it with "Where" value

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

My database look like this

```
**Code** | **Name** | **CodeParent** | **Level**
-XXX-| --TOP-| ----000000----| --0--
-YYY-| --TOP-| ----000000----| --0--
-AAA-| -Lower| ------XXX------| -1-
-BBB-| Lower2| ------AAA------| -2-
-CCC-| -Lower| ------YYY------| -1-
```

Ok let say I want to select from this table like

```
Select *
from table
where Code = 'XXX'
```

And retrieve data like

```
**Code** | **Name** | **CodeParent** | **Level**
-XXX-| --TOP-| ----000000----| --0--
-AAA-| -Lower| ------XXX------| -1-
-BBB-| Lower2| ------AAA------| -2-
```

I've been searching for day but still having no idea how to do it.

Is my database design good enough?

I tried to select like

```
Select * From table where Code = 'XXX'
Union All
Select * From table where CodeParent = 'XXX'
```

The table has no limit level

So, after level 2 I can't figure it out how to do it.

Comment: FYI, you could search for `recursive cte mssql`

Comment: In SQL Server there is a hierarchy data type https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx which provides many helper methods. In your case I believe you can use the `IsAncestor` helper. But first you need to load your data into this datatype which is non trivial. The other standard method for doing what you want is assign a 'flat path' column which describes he elements entire path from the root in one flat string. You just use `LIKE` on the string to search

Comment: One relatively simple option for representing hierarchical data is to use [nested sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).  Using nested sets, retrieving data is very easy and efficient, but inserts/updates can be a bit complicated, so nested sets may or may not make sense depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks you everyone, A flat path method is interesting.

Comment: A now-deleted answer offered [this helpful link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a recursive cte, consider the following:

You may notice the hierarchy is presented in the proper order.  You may also notice the Range Keys (R1/R2).  These can be used for non-recursive aggregation, selection criteria, and/or navigation.  Putting this code in a Table-Valued-Function may be the wise choice.

```
Declare @YourTable table (Code varchar(25),CodeParent  varchar(25),Name varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values 
 ('XXX', NULL,'Top')
,('YYY', NULL,'Top')
,('AAA','XXX','Lower')
,('BBB','AAA','Lower 2')
,('CCC','YYY','Lower')

Declare @Top    varchar(25) = null      --<<  Sets top of Hier NULL otherwise specific ID
Declare @Fetch  varchar(25) = null      --<<  Null for Entier Hier try 'BBB'
Declare @Nest   varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by Name) as varchar(500))
            ,Code
            ,CodeParent 
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Name 
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,'') = case when @Top is null then isnull(CodeParent ,'') else Code end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',10000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.Name)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.Code
            ,r.CodeParent 
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.Name 
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.CodeParent  = p.Code)
     ,cteR1 as (Select *,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteP)
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.Code,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.Code )
     ,cteHB as (
                Select A.R1  
                      ,B.R2
                      ,A.Code
                      ,A.CodeParent 
                      ,A.Lvl
                      ,Name = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.Name
                 From cteR1 A
                 Join cteR2 B on A.Code=B.Code
               )
Select Distinct A.*
 From  cteHB A
 Join  cteHB B on B.Code = IsNull(@Fetch,A.Code) and (@Fetch is not null and A.R1 between B.R1 and B.R2 or B.R1 between A.R1 and A.R2) 
 Order By A.R1
```

**When @Top = null and @Fetch = null**

You'll get the entire hierarchy

[image]

**When @Top = 'AAA' and @Fetch = null**

You'll get the descendants of AAA

[image]

**When @Top = null and @Fetch = 'CCC'**

You'll get the ancestors of CCC

[image]

Comment: Thanks,It works perfect for me.

But one more question, from this entire hierachy if I need to show only 'XXX' and its children 

How to do it

Comment: @PoyZHarmful set (at)Top ='XXX'

Answer (score 0):

Try this with other sample data and let me know.

```
Declare @YourTable table (Code varchar(25)
CodeParent  varchar(25),Name varchar(50))

Insert into @YourTable values 
 ('XXX', NULL,'Top')
,('YYY', NULL,'Top')
,('AAA','XXX','Lower')
,('BBB','AAA','Lower 2')
,('CCC','YYY','Lower')
declare @input varchar(25)='XXX'
;with CTE as
(
select *,0 [Level] from @YourTable
where code=@input
union ALL
select t.code,t.CodeParent,t.Name
,[Level]+1
 from @YourTable t
inner join cte c on c.code=t.CodeParent
)

select * from CTE
```